# CSS Border on the inside of div

Tags: css

Ok, so i have several divs with the same width but one of them has a border that's sticking out of the pattern.

[image: border]

is there a way to make it so the border goes inside the div? I've tried

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Here is what I got so far

```css
#firstDiv {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 480;
  margin-right: 10;
  background: #eeeeee;
  border-left: 10px solid #608cc9;
  padding-top: 15;
  padding-bottom: 15;
  text-align: center;
}
#right {float: right}
.divList {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 480;
  margin-right: 10;
  background: #fdead3;
  padding-top: 15;
  padding-bottom: 15;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="right">
  <div id="firstDiv">
    <span>NA STANDINGS</span>
  </div>
  <div class="divList">
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the HTML

Comment: Provide a complete example (not only css and image).

Comment: 4 lines of HTML is not a complete example. create a snippet or jsfiddle example.

Comment: @lsaadev I've updated your code to snippet. You can see that it works exactly as you want. You can now change it to demonstrates the problem...

Comment: http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow  notice the `inset` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your comment with the actual code, the problem is with the `margin` on the `.rankDisplayer` div.

```
.rankDisplayer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border-color: #eeeeee;
    margin: 10;
}
```

Remove the `margin: 10` you have there and it will be ok.
Another option - change it to `margin: 10 0` (this way you keep the top-bottom margin and remove the left-right ones).

Comment: I didnt really want to make the rest larger but it won't affect anything, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Border cannot be *in* the div, that's a thing of padding. If you want to vertically align them, I think you can extend the one of the bottom or make a bit smaller the top one. To de this, use the `padding`:

```
#firstDiv {
    ...
    width: 470px;
}

//OR

#divList {
    ...
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Now I propose you one change in the CSS. You have 2 ids that have almost the same CSS properties, so: Why don't you create a class for these divs?

```
#firstDiv {
    width: 470px;
    background: #eeeeee;
    border-left: 10px solid #608cc9;
    padding: 15px 0;

}
.divList {
    width: 480px;
    background: #fdead3;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 10px;
}

.divs_from_right_div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;

}
```